# Meteor: How can I sort a collection on a session variable?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to write a helper method that returns a list of accounts-facebook based user profiles sorted on a sub-field of the profile document. The helper should rely on two session variables to specify the sub-field and order to sort on. The session variables can be updated via the UI, causing the list to re-render in the new order. Something like:

```
Session.set('sortby', "profile.email");
Session.set('sortorder', "-1");

Template.userlist.users = function() {
   Meteor.users.find({}, {sort:{Session.get('sortby'):Session.get('sortorder')}});
}
```

Using `Session.get('sortby')` as the property name produces an error though. So the question is, how can I use a session variable to specify the sort field name?

Comment: did you try to convert your Session.get('sortorder') to integer?

Comment: `   Meteor.users.find({}, {sort:{Session.get('sortby'):+Session.get('sortorder')}});
`

Comment: Which error are you getting here? can you post that error trace?

Comment: The error is on Session.get('sortby'). The compiler claims the dot character is illegal there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize an Object and associate the key and value to it. Then pass it to the query. E.g.:

```
var filter = {sort: {}};
filter.sort[Session.get('sortby')] = Session.get('sortorder');
Meteor.users.find({}, filter);
```

But please, verify if it's undefined before assigning it :)

Answer (score 0):

Placing `Session.get('sortby')` directly in sort specifier will give a syntax error.

Use an `if-else` block before the query to find out which value the Session contains, and put that field-name in query instead of `Session.get()` like:

```
if( Session.equals('sortBy', 'profile_email') ){
   return  Meteor.users.find({}, {sort:{'profile_email':Session.get('sortorder')}});
} 
else if( Session.equals('sortBy', 'other_value') ) {
   return  Meteor.users.find({}, {sort:{'other_value':Session.get('sortorder')}});
}
```